# How can I pass id to my print page in ajax success

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, ajax, codeigniter

[image]

In above image I select 3 records `MR No`  7,8,9 that selected records insert successfully in my data base but I want to get that ids in my ajax success to pass print page

view:

```
$('#allocate').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
        var allVals = [];
        var saleid  = [];
        $('input[name=selectedBilties]:checked').each(function() {
          allVals.push($(this).val());
          saleid.push($(this).attr('saleid'));
        });

        var formData  = new FormData();
        var agent     = $('#agent').val();
        var rec_type  = $('#rec_type').val();

        formData.append("agent",agent);
        formData.append("rec_type",rec_type);

        for (var i = 0; i < allVals.length; i++) {
            formData.append('due_ids[]', allVals[i]);
        }
         alertify.confirm('Payment Recovery Allocation', 'Do you want to Allocate ?', function(){ 

           $.ajax({
                url :"<?php echo base_url();?>crossing/payment_rec_allocation/PaymentRecAllocationController/createPaymentAllocation",
                type:"POST",
                dataType: "json",                
                data:formData,  
                contentType:false,
                cache:false,
                processData:false,
                  beforeSend: function () {
                  $("#allocate").attr("disabled", true);
                },
                success: function(data){
                      console.log(data);
                      if(data.PaymentRecAllocation.form_status =='false'){}
                      else if(data.PaymentRecAllocation.form_status=='true'){
                        alertify.confirm('Payment Recovery Allocation', 'Do you want to print ? ', function(){ 
                        window.location.href =" <?php echo base_url(); ?>crossing/payment_rec_allocation/PaymentRecAllocationController/printCollectionRecPage"
                        },
                          function(){
                           location.href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>", 'refresh';
                        });
                   }
              } 
           });
       }, function(){ 
      });
   });
```

Controller:

```
public function createPaymentAllocation(){    

    $bilty_ids         = $this->input->post('due_ids');
    $biltyCount        = count($bilty_ids);

     $agent          = $this->input->post('agent');
     $due_to         = $this->input->post('due_to');

      for($i = 0; $i < $biltyCount; $i++){

      $data = array(
            'agent_id'            =>$agent,
            'pay_dueto'           =>$due_to,
            'mr_no'               =>$bilty_ids[$i],
             );
      $modelResult = $this->PayRecAllModel->inserPaymentAllocation($data);
    }

      if(!empty($modelResult)){
         $data['PaymentRecAllocation'] = array(
                'form_status'     => 'true',
                'form_message'    => 'Payment Recovery  has been successfully Allocate',
                );
      }else{
            $data['PaymentRecAllocation'] = array(
                'form_status'     => 'false',
                'form_message'    => 'Something went wrong.'
            );
      }
      echo json_encode($data);
  }
```

Model:

```
 public function inserPaymentAllocation($data){
  if($this->db->insert('payment_rec_allocn', $data)){       
          return   true;
   }else {
          return  false;
   }
}
```

After insert data that 3 records ids i want to get in variable to page following print page function

```
window.location.href =" <?php echo base_url(); ?>crossing/payment_rec_allocation/PaymentRecAllocationController/printCollectionRecPage";
```

I do not know how gets id in variable and pass to my print page.

Comment: you need to send only 3 ids or no of selected ids?

Comment: @M.Hemant in all my records I can select  all record or any no of record just I want selected records ids to pass my print page

Comment: that is not a *view*, that is just javascript codes, show the html form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, like your json response you can use your selected id as response
Controller :

```
$mrIDArray = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $biltyCount; $i++) {

    $data = array(
        'agent_id' => $agent,
        'pay_dueto' => $due_to,
        'mr_no' => $bilty_ids[$i],
    );
    array_push($mrIDArray,$bilty_ids[$i]);
    $modelResult = $this->PayRecAllModel->inserPaymentAllocation($data);
}

if (!empty($modelResult)) {
    $data['PaymentRecAllocation'] = array(
        'form_status' => 'true',
        'form_message' => 'Payment Recovery  has been successfully Allocate',
        'mr_ids'=>  implode(',', $mrIDArray);
    );
} else {
    $data['PaymentRecAllocation'] = array(
        'form_status' => 'false',
        'form_message' => 'Something went wrong.',
        'mr_ids'=>  implode(',', $mrIDArray);
    );
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

OR
js:

```
var mrIds = "";
for (var i = 0; i < allVals.length; i++) {
     formData.append('due_ids[]', allVals[i]);
     mrIds = mrIds + allVals[i] + ",";
}
window.location.href =" <?php echo base_url(); ?>crossing/payment_rec_allocation/PaymentRecAllocationController/printCollectionRecPage/"+mrIds;
```

After above thing you can handle you parameter in php

Comment: I try js code but it gives my  `Uncaught ReferenceError: myIds is not defined` this error

Comment: did you write the same as I mentioned above?

Comment: updated code again, check and tell me what do you face?